# How do I trace HTTP packets with Wireshark?

Tags: http, wireshark, packet

What can I do in order to see packets that come from different sessions in a web page?
For example when I open [yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) there are different sessions in yahoo; I dont know how to see which packet is from yahoo server and which are from other websites. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider to use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) instead, or if you aren't using Windows, some similar tool.

Browsers also include Developer Tools that allows you to track down HTTP request/responses...

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP response does not directly contain information showing what host it is from. You will need to infer from the TCP session and the corresponding HTTP request (which will usually contain a Host header) and the source IP address. (If you have seen the DNS request for this IP address, can infer the host name that was used)